# Amount of Polylines displayable in google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

i just worked with the google maps api for two days in order to display a network for my university project.
Therefore i want to display several polylines with a code that is generated with VBA out of an Access Database.
It worked fine during first tests, but with increasing the number of polylines over 300-400 the generated html file just opens an empty tab in my browser.
This issue is happening in every browser such as Internet Explorer, Firefox and Opera which i have tested so far.

For the code, please visit https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/maps/lss2vF5r-jo where i have posted this question as well.

As you might noticed, the frame code origins from the simple polyline example provided by google.
I know that this is a rather primitive approach and that there are better solutions possible with deeper knowledge in JAVA script.

Please can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong and if it is possible to display 600 polylines or more with this approach?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: Should be possible.  The only limits are the memory on your computer and the browser running the javascript.  [Example of ~13000 polylines on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/USA_rails.kmz) (they come from a KMZ file but are rendered as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 polylines) works for me on my desktop PC in Chrome (firefox and even IE).

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, use a KmlLayer or a FusionTablesLayer to render the polylines (those both use tile based rendering of the data), but beware, both have limitations on complexity of the data (my 13K polyline KMZ file won't load in KmlLayer, Kml Status:DOCUMENT_TOO_LARGE).  600 polylines of 2 points each (1200 coordinates) should work fine with any of the options.  I suspect a problem with your code or your backend.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I allready heard that it should be possible to display all the lines but for some reason doesn't work. Also in the example link you posted i can't see any layers or lines, I just get an Out of Memory error [line 138] after some seconds. What really drives me mad about my problem is that with 300 lines everything works fine while with 600 or more lines there isn't displayed anything at all. So I guess the java code generally works due to the fact that i generate it automatically for everyline and put it in one file together afterwards?

Comment: If you want us to debug your code, you need to post a link to your live map. If it's not on a live web server, use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll do that as soon as possible.

Comment: If you are getting an Out of Memory error with the example I posted, the problem is not Google Maps, it is the resources available on the device you are using to access it.  What browser?  What operating system?  If it is a PC, how much RAM/Hard Disk space?

Comment: Hey 
i have Firefox, Opera and IE with 8 GB of Ram and 150 GB space on a SSD-Drive.

Here the link to the one with 300 that works: http://jsfiddle.net/kbQ97/

And here the link with the file with the 600 lines that doesn't work
http://jsfiddle.net/34acc/